# In SQL, how to aggregate on a field inside the table

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, max

I'm sorry the TITLE is not so specific. I'll try to explain:
I'm new to SQL. I'm at work and wrote a query which has 9 columns that takes information out of many tables.
on the 9th column are names of types of machines, on the 3rd are value representing the time a machine worked in a month.
I need to add a 10th column which will have for each type of machine, the maximum of 3rd columns for this type. 
lets say there are 5 machines of type XR (5 rows in the table) with times (3rd column) of  1,2,3,4,5 (in hours). I need that on the 10th column, all rows where type of machine is XR will have the value 5, as it is the maximum for this type of machine.

How do i do that?

Any help would be very appreciated!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `SQL Server`, `Oracle` and `PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT  *, MAX(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY col9)
FROM    mytable
```

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  mt.*, maxcol3
FROM    (
        SELECT  col9, MAX(col3) AS maxcol3
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
JOIN    mytable mt
ON      mt.col9 = q.col9
```

Comment: Thanx! It's PLSQL, it doesn't like the (col3).
Any idea what can replace it?

Comment: @DanaRoot: substitute your actual column names. You haven't provided them in your post. Also, please copy and paste the error message instead of "it does not like": it's not very descriptive.

Comment: It works!! Thanx you very much Quassnoi!
I apologize for not copying the message.  Anyway, 
Again,  Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelBuen,  There's a time limit before you can accept an answer.