# How to sort records by most recent records in other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, comments, sql-order-by

I am trying to order statements by most recent activity (comments). However if a statement doesn't have a comment, the below query doesn't display that statement at the end. How can I change the query, so statements with no comments are displayed and displayed last?

```
SELECT 
  `statements`.`id`,
  `statement`,
  `statements`.`timestamp`,
  `statements`.`published`,
  `image`,
  `statements`.`author_id`,
  `statements`.`ip_address`,
  `username`,
  `comment_count` 
FROM
  (`statements`) 
  INNER JOIN `comments` 
    ON `comments`.`statement_id` = `statements`.`id` 
  LEFT JOIN `users` 
    ON `users`.`id` = `statements`.`author_id` 
WHERE `statements`.`published` > 0 
GROUP BY `statements`.`id` 
ORDER BY MAX(comments.id)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In SQL, how to aggregate on a field inside the table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412033/in-sql-how-to-aggregate-on-a-field-inside-the-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `LEFT JOIN` for `comments` table:

```
SELECT `statements`.`id`, `statement`, `statements`.`timestamp`, `statements`.`published`, `image`, `statements`.`author_id`, `statements`.`ip_address`, `username`, `comment_count`
FROM (`statements`) 
    LEFT JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`statement_id` = `statements`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `statements`.`author_id` 
WHERE `statements`.`published` > 0
GROUP BY `statements`.`id` 
ORDER BY MAX(comments.id) DESC
```

Ordering descending by maximal comment id will put statement with most recent comment at top.

Regarding MySQL documentation  [Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

> When doing an ORDER BY, NULL values are presented first if you do
>   ORDER BY ... ASC and last if you do ORDER BY ... DESC.

statements without comments (`MAX(comments.id) IS NULL`) must be placed at the bottom of result.

Comment: @user3835276, try not to use the phrase "doesn't work". We regard it generally as the least helpful fault report possible `:-)`. Consider this answer a hint to get you going?

Comment: I expect a `statement` would always have a `user`, so expect that could be an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @halfer the query orders topics/statements/threads by most recent comment activity. however, the query fails to display items that do not have a comment. for instance. (statement 1: comment today; statement 2: comment yesterday; statement 3: no comments). except statement 3 doesn't show

Comment: @halfer, In this case you need `INNER JOIN` `users` but not `comments`

Comment: Try taking off the `ORDER BY` to see what affect that has.

Comment: @halfer tried it. the statements with no comments still dont appear

Comment: @user3835276, check if you have statements without commens that match  condition `WHERE statements.published > 0`

Comment: @Nicolai: The ORDER BY clause could be something like `ORDER BY (MAX(comments.id) IS NULL) , MAX(comments.id)` to get the statements without comments last. Else your statement seems fine to me.

Comment: I've added `DESC` in `ORDER BY` clause, please review my answer.

Comment: @Nicolai Yes that should be right, I was being mislead by the original query. It would automatically take care of the NULL values - using the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @user3835276: "the statements with no comments still [don't] appear" - create a SQL Fiddle then, since they should appear, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it slightly different altogether:

```
SELECT 
  statements.*,
  cm.id 
FROM
  statements LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT statement_id, MAX(id) id FROM comments GROUP BY statement_id) cm 
    ON cm.statement_id = statements.id
  LEFT JOIN users
    ON users.id = statements.author_id 
WHERE statements.published > 0 
ORDER BY cm.id;
```

This way you don't depend on MySQL group by hack and this query should work in any other database.

Comment: This query doesn't need MySQL hack. It is enought to put MAX(comments.id) in `SELECT` clause with alias `max_comment_id` and you can use this alias in `ORDER BY` in most datbases.

Comment: then you need to mention all columns in GROUP BY statement